# Does not produce the same output Concurrency Go worker pool

Tags: go, concurrency

I am writing a program that concurrently reads word by word from a text file to compute the occurrences using channels and worker pool pattern

The program works in the following flow:

1. Read a text file (`readText` function)
2. `readText` function sends each word to the `word` channel
3. Each goroutine executes `countWord` function that counts word in a map
4. Each goroutine returns a map and the worker function passes the Result value of struct to the `resultC` channel
5. Test function creates a map based on the result values coming from the `resultC` channel
6. Print the map created from step 5

The program works, but when I try to put `fmt.Println(0)` to see the process as shown below

```
func computeTotal() {
    i := 0
    for e := range resultC {
        total[e.word] += e.count
        i += 1
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

The program terminates without showing/counting all the words

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 all goroutines finished 16 17 18 map[but:1 cat's:1 crouched:1 fur:1 he:2 imperturbable:1 it:1 pointed:1 sat:1 snow:1 stiffly:1 the:1 was:2 with:1] total words: 27 38 ... 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 Time taken for reading the book 5.8145ms
```

The program shows results correctly if I uncomment the fmt.println() in the compute Total function statement here and the output is as shown below

```
all goroutines finished
map[a:83 about:4 above:2 absolute:1 accepted:1 across:1 affection:1 after:1 again:5  wonder:2 wood:5 wooded:1 woody:1 work:1 worked:2 world:4 would:11 wrapped:1 wrong:1 yellow:2 yielded:1 yielding:1 counts continues ......]
total words:  856
Time taken for reading the book 5.9924ms
```

here is my implementation of readtext

```
//ensure close words at the right timing
func readText() {

    file, err := os.Open(FILENAME)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        word := strings.ToLower(scanner.Text())
        words <- strings.Trim(word, ".,:;")

    }
    //time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    close(words)
}
```

here is my count word implementation using worker pool

```
//call countWord func,
func workerPool() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 1; i <= NUMOFWORKER; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(&wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("all goroutines finished")
    close(resultC)
}

func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    var tempMap = make(map[string]int)
    for w := range words {
        resultC <- countWord(w, tempMap) //retuns Result value
    }
    wg.Done()

}

//creates a map each word
func countWord(word string, tempMap map[string]int) Result {
    _, ok := tempMap[word]
    if ok {
        tempMap[word]++
        return Result{word, tempMap[word] + 1}

    }
    return Result{word, 1}

}
```

Finally, this is the main function

```
const FILENAME = "cat.txt"
const BUFFERSIZE = 3000
const NUMOFWORKER = 5

var words = make(chan string, BUFFERSIZE) //job
var resultC = make(chan Result, BUFFERSIZE)

var total = map[string]int{}

type Result struct {
    word  string
    count int
}

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    go readText()
    go computeTotal()
    workerPool() //blocking
    fmt.Println(total)
    endTime := time.Now()
    timeTaken := endTime.Sub(startTime)
    fmt.Println("total words: ", len(total))
    fmt.Println("Time taken for reading the book", timeTaken)
}
```

I have been looking for why the program does not show consistent results but I could not figure it out yet. How can I make a change to the program so that it produces the same outcome?

Comment: Unless you're doing this for educational purposes this is pretty much pointless. Updating a counter and updating a map isn't enough work to justify concurrency, and using only a single goroutine will likely be faster and much easier to understand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite your `computeTotal` function in a following way:

```
func computeTotal(done chan struct{}) {
    defer close(done)
    i := 0
    for e := range resultC {
        total[e.word] += e.count
        i += 1
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}

func main() {

   computeTotalDone := make(chan struct{})
   go computeTotal(computeTotalDone)
   ...
   workerPool() //blocking
   <-computeTotalDone
   fmt.Println(total)
}
```

The reason why adding `fmt.Println` leads to invalid result is that your implementation has a race condition. As printing total result in main function `fmt.Println(total)` and `computeTotal` function runs in parallel there is no guarantee that `computeTotal` handles all messages before `fmt.Println(total)` is invoked. Without `fmt.Println` the `computeTotal` function is fast enough on your computer to produce correct results.

The proposed solution ensures that `computeTotal` completes before `fmt.Println(total)` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

The `countWord` function always returns a result with count == 1.

Here's a version of the function that increments the count:

```
func countWord(word string, tempMap map[string]int) Result {
    count := tempMap[word] + 1
    tempMap[word] = count
    return Result{word, count}
}
```

But hold that thought!  The `computeTotal` function assumes that the result `count` is 1.  Given that the workers in the question always send `Result{word, 1}` as `computeTotal` expects, we can cut the workers out of the picture by sending `Result{word, 1}` directly from `readText`.  Here's the code:

```
func computeTotal() {
    i := 0
    for e := range resultC {
        total[e.word] += e.count
        i += 1
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}

func readText() {
    file, err := os.Open(FILENAME)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        word := strings.ToLower(scanner.Text())
        resultC <- Result{strings.Trim(word, ".,:;"), 1}
    }
    close(resultC)
}

main() {
    ...
    go readText()
    computeTotal()
    fmt.Println(total)
    ...
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vS83-D1JWUJ).

The overhead of the channel operations probably negates any benefit of running `computeTotal` and `readText` in separate goroutines. Here's the code combined into a single goroutine:

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open(FILENAME)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    var total = map[string]int{}
    for scanner.Scan() {
        word := strings.ToLower(strings.Trim(scanner.Text(), ".,:;"))
        total[word]++
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bItqxMTF8dO).

The `countWord` function in the question makes me think your goal was to count words in each worker and merge the result for a total. Here's the code for that:

```
func computeTotal() {
    for i := 1; i <= NUMOFWORKER; i++ {
        m := <-resultC
        for word, count := range m {
            total[word] += count
        }
    }
}

func workerPool() {
    for i := 1; i <= NUMOFWORKER; i++ {
        go worker()
    }
}

func worker() {
    var tempMap = make(map[string]int)
    for w := range words {
        tempMap[w]++
    }
    resultC <- tempMap
}

...
var resultC = make(chan map[string]int)
...

func main() {
    ...
    go readText()
    workerPool()
    computeTotal()
    ...
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mHhh6Tm97ol).

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/BgYkWI1Gjmv . `But hold that thought! The computeTotal function assumes that the result count is 1.` I could not make sense of that. Though, I agree, we can cut the workers out of the equation.

Comment: @mh-cbon `computTotal` executes `total[e.word] += e.count` for each result sent from a worker. A worker sends a result for each word.  The value `e.count` must equal 1 for `total[e.word]` to equal the count of words.  I cannot make sense of your playground example.  Did you intend to call `countWord2` from `main`?

Comment: oh yes.... What a mistake in my playground. nevermind, I have read this whole post upside down. I should not have commented.